# How leaflet loads tile maps for custom rules？

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Now there is a map of custom tile rules locally. There is already a custom JavaScript library that can be called normally. Now I need to replace this library with leaflet. How to use the algorithm in the old JavaScript library and leaflet to make the tile map Normal call?

The tile map projection rule is Mercator projection. The tile size is irregular. The width is 256 pixels. The height is the same on each line, but the different line heights are different. The old JavaScript library defines the ellipsoid parameters. Various levels of scale, rank number calculation rules, etc., now want to use leaflet to load these tile maps, how to use the old rules and leaflet combination?

MapBase defines various basic parameters, loadMapImage is a key function

```
function LoadMapImage() {
    var tileLoadInfo = mapBase.getViewInfo();
    MapInfo.Map.basemapslicedlayer.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < tileLoadInfo.TileInfo.length; i++) {
        if (MapInfo.Map.Tiles[tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Col + "_" + tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Row + "_" + tileLoadInfo.Mode] == undefined) {
            if (tileLoadInfo.Mode == 6) {
                var src = DNCOptions.url + "&" + DNCOptions.paramX + "=" + tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Row + "&" + DNCOptions.paramY + "=" + tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Col + "&" + DNCOptions.paramZ + "=" + tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Level + "&SessionID=" + WinfoDNCSessionID
            } else if (tileLoadInfo.Mode == 8 || tileLoadInfo.Mode == 9) {
                var level = tileLoadInfo.Level + 2;
                if (tileLoadInfo.Mode == 9) {
                    level = tileLoadInfo.Level - 3
                }
                src = MapInfo.ServicePath + "?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=CacheMap&Y=" + tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Col + "&X=" + tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Row + "&LEVEL=" + level + "&LAYERS=" + DNCOptions.layername + "&SessionID=" + WinfoDNCSessionID
            } else {
                var src = MapInfo.ServicePath + "?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WINFODNC&X=" + tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Col + "&Y=" + tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Row + "&LEVEL=" + tileLoadInfo.Level + "&LAYERS=" + tileLoadInfo.Mode + "&SessionID=" + WinfoDNCSessionID
            }
            MapInfo.Map.Tiles[tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Col + "_" + tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Row + "_" + tileLoadInfo.Mode] = w$("<img>").css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Offset_x,
                top: tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Offset_y
            }).attr("src", src)
        }
        MapInfo.Map.basemapslicedlayer.append(MapInfo.Map.Tiles[tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Col + "_" + tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Row + "_" + tileLoadInfo.Mode].css({
            position: "absolute",
            left: tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Offset_x,
            top: tileLoadInfo.TileInfo[i].Offset_y
        }))
    }
}
```

```
    function GetTileInfoByViewportParam(vp) {
        var Box = {};
        var i, row1, row2, col1, col2, hTileSize;
        var L, R, T, B;
        var LT = ScreenPoint2Coordinate(vp, 0, 0);
        Box.Top = LT[0];
        Box.Left = LT[1];
        var RB = ScreenPoint2Coordinate(vp, vp.Width, vp.Height);
        Box.Bottom = RB[0];
        Box.Right = RB[1];
        var rc = CalculateTile(LevelZeroTileSizeDegrees, Box, vp.Level);
        row1 = rc[0];
        row2 = rc[2];
        col1 = rc[1];
        col2 = rc[3];
        var LRTB = CalculateTileExtend(LevelZeroTileSizeDegrees, vp.Level, row1, col1);
        L = LRTB[0];
        R = LRTB[1];
        T = LRTB[2];
        B = LRTB[3];
        var Offset = Coordinate2ScreenPoint(vp, T, L);
        vp.Offset_x = Offset[0];
        vp.Offset_y = Offset[1];
        MapViewInfo.Level = vp.Level;
        MapViewInfo.Box = Box;
        i = 0;
        var offsety = vp.Offset_y;
        MapViewInfo.TileInfo = [];
        for (var j = row1; j >= row2; j--) {
            hTileSize = CalculateTileSize(vp.Level, j, col1);
            var offsetx = vp.Offset_x;
            for (var z = col1; z <= col2; z++) {
                var tileInfo = {};
                tileInfo.Row = j;
                tileInfo.Col = z;
                tileInfo.Height = hTileSize;
                tileInfo.Widht = TileSize;
                tileInfo.Offset_x = offsetx;
                tileInfo.Offset_y = offsety;
                offsetx += TileSize;
                MapViewInfo.TileInfo[i] = tileInfo;
                i++
            }
            offsety += hTileSize
        }
        return MapViewInfo
    };
```

According to the default initialization map method of leaflet, the parameters can only be retrieved to the blank tile.

Comment: The `?REQUEST=GetMap` bit leads me to think you're dealing with WMS or WTMS. You should find out if you're dealing with well-known tiled map services first, and if that's the case, look how to load such a service into Leaflet.

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed the wmts service, but the slicing rules are custom, so there is a problem with the method of calling standard wmts, because the tiles are not 256*256, and the height is not the same.

Comment: No, TMS and WMTS tile matrix sets are regular (see the specs). There should be no reason for deforming the shape of the grid, and you should try displaying the WMTS tiles "as they are". That code may be a hackish attempt to do raster reprojection in the client, which is (IMHO) the wrong approach.

Comment: What do you mean by re-slicing the map, sliced to a size of 256 x 256 pixels to fit the wtms standard? Now that this tile has an old JavaScript library that can be called normally, can you combine the methods in this library with leaflets? Is there such a possibility?